# ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = true and waiting for process exit

Tags: c#, .net, shellexecute

I want to use shell executable in order to respect user preferences of application to be started, but I also need to know when that particular application is closed.

```
Process editProcess = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = filename;
startInfo.Verb = "edit";
startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
editProcess.StartInfo = startInfo;

// start the default editor
editProcess.Start();
editProcess.WaitForExit();
```

WaitForExit seems to return when the shell process exits and not when the real process exits.

Is there a better way of knowing when started application is exited than manually parsing registry, finding correct application to start and explicitly start that app without shell execute?

Comment: I am having the similar issue. Did you managed to solve this?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68180006/11683

Answer (score 1):

Handle the process exited event:

```
editProcess.Exited += process_Exited;
```

Comment: I tried that as well, but that behaves in the same undesired way, namely fires when shell process? exits and the started application is still running..