# ProcessStartInfo hangs when UseShellExecute = true

Tags: c#, processstartinfo

I was running some exe with `ProcessStartInfo`

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("my.exe");
startInfo.Arguments = "foo.txt bar.txt";
startInfo.WorkingDirectory = path;
Process process = Process.Start(startInfo);
process.WaitForExit();
```

It was working fine on my PC, but when I move the code to another PC, the same code keep hanging.
After some trying, I was able to fix it by setting `UseShellExecute` to `false` (and use absolute path for the exe filename).

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(@"~\mypath"),"my.exe"));
startInfo.Arguments = "foo.txt bar.txt";
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
Process process = Process.Start(startInfo);
process.WaitForExit();
```

The question is why? Why does using shell hang the process? What is the difference between using or not using shell to execute?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Not sure I'd WaitForExit in an ASP.NET context

Comment: Are you using the same version of .NET? Note that `UseShellExecute`'s default value is true in .NET Framework and false in .NET Core (including .NET 5 and 6).

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255086/when-do-we-need-to-set-processstartinfo-useshellexecute-to-true answer your question ?

Comment: Rather, https://stackoverflow.com/a/68182627/11683.

Comment: @41686d6564 both are .NET framework 4.5.2
Thanks for the links, but they don't seem to answer why my process won't exit.